# which swig functions require %newobject to avoid a memory leak in python

Tags: python-3.x, swig

If we return value created by SWIG_NewObjectPtr without flags, it will have reference count of 1 and would never be garbage collected. In order to avoid it I have to use %newobject in .i file.

However, there are quite a few swig primitives that could be used to make the value returned into python. I suspect that some of them should be also annotated as %newobject.

Is there a list or should blindly annotate all functions returning anything into python?
Is there a way to apply %newobject globally or per-file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `SWIG_NewPointerObj`, Python will track the reference if needed.  Set the `own` flag.  If that return value isn't assigned to a variable its reference count would be decremented.  `%newobject` isn't intended for Python objects.

`%newobject` is used to indicate that a function returns an C/C++ allocated object that isn't reference counted, such as `return new char[50];` or `return (char*)malloc(1000);`.  In the previous example SWIG will create a Python string by copying the data, but doesn't know to free the returned pointer without `%newobject`.  You may also need to write a `%typemap(newfree)` if SWIG doesn't already have one for the type.

References:

- [11.3.3 Using %newobject to release memory](https://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Library_nn11)
- [14.2 Object ownership and %newobject](https://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Customization_ownership)

Comment: Sorry my reading is completely different: "When %newobject is supplied, many language modules will arrange to take ownership of the return value. This allows the value to be automatically garbage-collected when it is no longer in use."

I want garbage collection.

Comment: @uuu777 The next sentence is: "However, this depends entirely on the target language".  When a function for example returns `char*` SWIG's Python response is to copy the data up to null termination to a `PyBytes` object, but doesn't know if it should free the `char*` after the copy and doesn't unless told.  `%newobject` tells it.  It has nothing to do with reference counting.  It indicates cleaning up a memory leak.  The `PyBytes` object is reference counted and garbage collected appropriately by Python.